# Divide multiple columns by another column in pandas error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 12 columns. I want to divide each column (except the first and the last one) by the last column.

The code below is not working:

```
df.iloc[:,1:-2].div(df.lastcolumn,axis=0)
```

The error is:

```
unsupported operands types for /: float and instance method.
```

I have  a couple of Nan values and 0 values in all columns of my dataframe.

The dataype of each column is float.

Thanks

Comment: Should be `df.iloc[:, 1:-1].div(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0)`

Comment: what is the behavior you seek for divisions involving nan or zero denominator? return nan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:-1].divide(df.iloc[:,-1], axis = 'rows')
```